# Why isn't my cookie being sent to the server?

Tags: google-chrome, http, cookies

When I make a request in Chrome to the webserver on my localhost, the headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.9.12
Date: Sat, 03 Sep 2016 18:44:54 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 520
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: session="\350C\243\0153RB`\225M4vyD\317\030"; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

When I make a subsequent request to the server, the headers are:

```
GET /api/larps HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.99.100
Connection: keep-alive
accept: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/json
Referer: https://192.168.99.100/simple.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Here is a webpage demonstrating the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    const fetch_get_json = url => _fetch(url, 'GET');
    const fetch_post_json = (url, data) => _fetch(url, 'POST', data);

    const _fetch = (url, method, data) => {
      console.log('fetching', url)
      const params = {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method
      }

      if (data) {
        params.body = JSON.stringify(data);
      };

      return fetch(url, params);
    }

    fetch_post_json('/api/login', {email: 'user', 'pwd': 'password'}).then(function() {
      fetch_get_json('/api/info');
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why isn't the cookie being sent?

Comment: As you probably realise, more information is needed here. What framework are you using on the server, what's the code you're using to set the cookie, where is that code used, etc.

Comment: You have the headers being sent from the server. Why is the code generating the headers relevant?

Comment: Same reason any other details are a great idea to add - are you using a standard framework? If so, it has documentation that might already cover this as a troubleshooting article or comment in the regular docs. If not, where's the client code? Is any JS triggering on the page you request, are you using an XHR or is this a straight up "I load static page X that has zero active content other than an empty html page, then I hit reload in the browser", there's a bit of information missing from your post that you assume is obvious, but isn't obvious until part of the post.

Comment: Sample code which demonstrates the problem updated.

Comment: Sanity check: are you sure cookies are enabled in the browser? And maybe: try to remove the ` character in the cookie data.

Comment: Cookies are being saved for other sites. And I've tried it with simple test data, and still no luck.

Comment: Are you seeing the "no cookie getting sent" for the `fetch` operation, or for full page reloads? I ask, because those are two completely different ways of requesting data as far as the browser is concerned, and I'm not seeing a `credentials: 'include'` in your fetch config, so there is no reason to expect the cookie data to be sent during the Fetch API call.

Comment: The issue was the fetch() call. I needed to set the credentials flag.